# How to know where belongs current IP

Tags: geolocation, ip, maps, layer, ip-geolocation

I do not know if it is possible to do it, I share a little the case: I need to get the district to which an IP belongs. So I was wondering if there is a way to draw different layers for each district on a map and if the ip is within one of these layers, get the district to which it belongs. Can this be done? Could Openstreet maps help? Or do I have to use google maps

Answer (score 0):

To get the district/region/subdivision from an IP address you will need to use an    IP geolocation service. Most include fields such as region and coordinates in their response. However, be aware that not all IP addresses will have this field populated, whatever the geolocation service you use.

Here is a response chunk using [Ipregistry](https://ipregistry.co):

> $ curl https://api.ipregistry.co/144.33.1.2?key=tryout&pretty=true

```
"location": {
  "continent": {
    "code": "NA",
    "name": "North America"
  },
  "country": {
    "area": 9629091,
    "borders": [
      "CA",
      "MX"
    ],
    "calling_code": "1",
    "capital": "Washington D.C.",
    "code": "US",
    "name": "United States"
  },
  "region": {
    "code": "US-MI",
    "name": "Michigan"
  },
  "city": "Dearborn",
  "postal": "48120",
  "latitude": 42.31146,
  "longitude": -83.19134
}
```

Once you have the region code or the coordinates you can use both, OpenStreetMap or Google Map to draw what you need.